# Chain assignment in Python for list

Tags: python, variable-assignment, infinite-loop

I am trying to understand chain assignment in Python.

If I run `x = x[1] = [1, 2]`, I get an infinite list `[1, [...]]`.

But if I run `x = x[1:] = [1, 2]`, I will get a normal list `[1, 1, 2]`.

How does it work in the background to make these two different results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, understand that in a chained assignment, the right-most expression is evaluated to an object. A reference to that object is then assigned to each target in sequence, from left to right. `x = y = z` is effectively the same as

```
t = z # A new temporary variable "t" to hold the result of evaluating z
x = t
y = t
del t
```

Second, you need to understand the difference between assigning `t`  to the *subscription* `x[1]` and to the *slicing* `x[1:]`. In the former, element 1 of `x` is replaced by `t`. In the latter, elements `x[1]`, `x[2]`, etc are replaced by `t[0]`, `t[1]`, etc, extending or shrinking `x` as necessary.

The first example is equivalent to

```
t = [1,2]
x = t
x[1] = t
del t
```

`x[1]` becomes a reference to `x` itself; `list.__repr__` can detect cycles like this and represents them with `...`. `x`, `x[1]`, `x[1][1]`, etc are all references to the original list `[1,2]`.

The second example is equivalent to

```
t = [1,2]
x = t
x[1:] = t
del t
```

In this case, no cycles are created. `x[1]` is replaced by a reference to `1`, not `x`/`t` itself, and `x` is extended to make `x[2]` a reference to `2`. (If it helps, think of `x[1:] = t` as producing the same result as `x = [x[0]]; x.extend(t)`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = x[1] = [1, 2]
```

In this case, `x` and `x[1]` are *the same object*.  Therefore x contains *itself*, which is represented by `...` in your output.

```
x = x[1:] = [1, 2]
```

In this case, `x` is a *slice*, and slices are *copies*.  so they are *not the same object*.

Comment: This is a slice *assignment*, though. Basically `x = [1,2]` is performed first, then the slice assignment assigns `1` to `x[1]` and appends `2` to `x` ("assigning" 2 to `x[2]`).

Answer (score 0):

## Explaining the outputs:

```
x = x[1] = [1, 2] # Output: [1, [...]]
```

The reason is that the list is not copied, but referenced.

- x[1] is a reference to the list [1, 2].
- When you assign x[1] to x, you are assigning a reference to the list [1, 2] to x.
- So x and x[1] are both references to the same list.
- When you change the list through one of the references, the change appears in the other reference as well. This is called aliasing.

---

```
x = x[1:] = [1, 2] # Output: [1, 1, 2]
```

The reason is that the list is copied, not referenced.

- x[1:] is slice of the list [1, 2].
- The slice is a copy of the list, not a reference to the list.
  When you assign x[1:] to x, you are assigning a copy of the list [1, 2] to x.
- So x and x[1:] are both copies of the same list.
- When you change the list through one of the references, the change does not appear in the other reference.